# Populate TreeView with non-Empty Folders

Tags: c#, treeview

```
private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();
    var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
}

private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles().Where(s => s.Extension == ".jpg"))
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
    return directoryNode;
}
```

using this code I can list all jpg files and folders from a given directory. But it will list empty folders of jpg files too. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to check whether there are any files on the return from the recursion, then add it if there are.

```
foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
{
    TreeNode subNode = CreateDirectoryNode(directory);
    if (subNode.Nodes.Count > 0)
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
}
```

Since you're doing a depth first search the nodes will effectively be culled from the leaf up to the root if there aren't any files.

Comment: It will cause a none ending loop

Comment: How will it do that? It ran just fine when I tested it here.  It's the exact same recursive call that was already happening, it's just checking for empty child nodes on the way back. Am I missing the obvious?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the number of sub directories is zero and the number of files in the directory is zero. If this is the case, you should not create the node.

One way to do this is to return `null` from the `CreateDirectoryNode` method if the directory does not meet the specification. And then only add sub nodes that are not `null`.

Consider this code:

```
private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();
    var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    var tree_node = CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo);

    if (tree_node != null)
        treeView.Nodes.Add(tree_node);
}

//This method will return null of the specified directory does not have sub folders or JPG files
private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    //Obtain all sub directories
    var sub_directories = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();

    //Obtain all JPG files
    var jpeg_files =
        directoryInfo.GetFiles()
            .Where(s => s.Extension.Equals(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .ToArray();

    //If the above arrays are empty, return null
    if (sub_directories.Length == 0 && jpeg_files.Length == 0)
        return null;

    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

    foreach (var directory in sub_directories)
    {
        var sub_node = CreateDirectoryNode(directory);

        if(sub_node != null) //Only add sub nodes if they are not null
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(sub_node);
    }

    foreach (var file in jpeg_files)
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));


    return directoryNode;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more details what is not working?

Comment: It is not showing some of sub folders containing jpg files.

Comment: Are you sure they have jpg extension? Maybe the extension they have is jpeg or some other extension.

Comment: In Some cases it will keep a directory which its sub directories are empty of jpg files. I mean In the way back it will keep root directory in some cases.